# Errors related to AssemblyInfo.cs and GlobalUsings.g.cs files after upgrading from .NET 7 to .NET 8 using Upgrade Assistant

Tags: c#, .net-8.0

I'm currently facing an issue that I need guidance on. I have a library project that I upgraded from .NET 7 to .NET 8 using the Upgrade Assistant. This project only references other projects and is itself referenced by other projects.

After the upgrade, I encountered the following two errors:

> 1. Error reading content of source file 'C:\Users\Sibetalaee\Desktop\MyProjNameEmptyTemplate\MyProjNameEmptyTemplatePackage\templates\MyProjName.Crawler\src\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Crawler.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries\obj\Debug\net8.0\Crawler.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries.AssemblyInfo.cs'
>    -- 'Could not find file 'C:\Users\Sibetalaee\Desktop\MyProjNameEmptyTemplate\MyProjNameEmptyTemplatePackage\templates\MyProjName.Crawler\src\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Crawler.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries\obj\Debug\net8.0\Crawler.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries.AssemblyInfo.cs'.'.

> 2. Error reading content of source file 'C:\Users\Sibetalaee\Desktop\MyProjNameEmptyTemplate\MyProjNameEmptyTemplatePackage\templates\MyProjName.Crawler\src\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Crawler.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries\obj\Debug\net8.0\Crawler.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries.GlobalUsings.g.cs'
>    -- 'Could not find file 'C:\Users\Sibetalaee\Desktop\MyProjNameEmptyTemplate\MyProjNameEmptyTemplatePackage\templates\MyProjName.Crawler\src\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Crawler.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries\obj\Debug\net8.0\Crawler.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries.GlobalUsings.g.cs'.'.

I've tried several solutions such as reinstalling the SDK, unloading and reloading the project, and restarting Visual Studio, but the errors persist. Also, I have enabled long path support in Windows 10.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Try closing VS, deleting bin and obj folders and then rebuilding the app.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2022---File-name-must-not-exceed-259/10469298?sort=active&topics=Fixed-in%3A+Visual+Studio+2017+version+15.3.1